# MySQL sum and Group By with data identifying info in second table

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I have a store type database that I need to run a report where I total all purchases made by one customer.

Due to special needs of this database for a store userIDs are stored in two parts: compID and userId. For example a user may have an ID of 'ABCD' where the 'AB' signifies the company they work for and 'CD' is their specific ID, but it still references back to the fact that it is matched with the 'AB' making it a unique value from any other 'CD' user values. (I know this is kind of weird way of doing it but the needs were to have as short of user Ids as possible while still having the most slots available.)

Anyways, my problem is that when I try to write a query to total up my purchases by one user I cannot find a way to bring extra info from a second table such as that user's name.

Here's may tables.

f_purchases table stores each sale with data such as the userID (and their compID), and value of a purchase

f_user table has in depth info about the user such as userID, compID, name, contact, etc.

When I select just the raw data this query works:

```
SELECT f_purchases.compID, f_purchases.userID, sum(f_purchases.amount) as Total FROM f_purchases GROUP BY f_purchases.compID, f_purchases.userID
```

But when I try to use a Join or multiple table query I cannot find a way to bring in identifying info from f_user such as name. I think I would be able to get f_user.name if I had something like

```
WHERE f_purchases.compID=f_user.compID AND f_purchases.userID=f_user.userID
```

My other thought was that I could somehow use concatenation to join the two parts of the ID, but I did not know where to start with that. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: So what do you get when you add that WHERE clause

Comment: @Melanie I went to rerun it with that and I don't know what I was doing wrong before but now it worked. Sorry for the initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I had something out of order before, but after trying it one more time it now sums everything correctly. Here's what worked:

```
SELECT f_user.first, f_purchases.compID, f_purchases.userID, sum( f_purchases.amount ) AS Total
FROM f_purchases, f_user
WHERE f_purchases.compID = f_user.compID
AND f_purchases.userID = f_user.userID
GROUP BY f_purchases.compID, f_purchases.userID
```

Sorry for the initial post.